# regex pattern validation in HTML

Tags: regex, html

I want to validate a text box that should not have

1. Spaces in the beginning
2. All spaces
3. Spaces in the end

Here is the `textbox` code:

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username..." required="required">
```

I can't use trim because of the implementation of the code is a bit complex, It would break other functionality. This is only a carry over project to me. So I decided to filter it out on the  `HTML` `textbox` it self. But I don't know how to do this.

**Update:**

By the way I'm asking for a `regex` pattern.

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/njUSJ/ ?

Comment: @Passerby That would do it.

Comment: If you enter only one character, it is invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^\S(?:[\s\S]*\S)?$
```

should do it.

Translated into English, it's

`^\S` - starts with a non-space character

`(?:...)?$` - optionally followed by ... which continues to the end of input

`[\s\S]*\S` - any number of any character, followed by a non-space character

Comment: Isn't `[\s\S]` the same as `.`?

Comment: @Havenard `.` will does not include a new-line - `[\s\S]` does.

Comment: Afaik `\s` matches newlines too. At least with the `/s` flag, but I guess it depends on the implementation.

Comment: @Havenard, no `.` and `[\s\S]` are not the same.  HTML5 specifies regexs in terms of the [EcmaScript spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.10.2.8), which defines `.` as "`Atom :: .` evaluates as follows: 1. Let A be the set of all characters except *LineTerminator*".

Comment: @Havenard, there is no `/s` flag in EcmaScript which is the controlling spec per [HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-pattern-attribute) which says "The pattern attribute ... If specified, the attribute's value must match the JavaScript Pattern production."

Comment: Well in either case you won't find newline in a `input type=text`.

Comment: @Havenard, You're probably right about `type=text`, though I don't know whether some exotic input method produces U+2028 or U+2029.  Why though would you argue with an answer on the basis that it doesn't treat newlines as special when it's in response to a question that doesn't request special treatment for newlines?

Comment: No, you are right. I'm just raising the question because `.` would do just fine. I found it weird seeing someone chosing `[\s\S]` instead.

Comment: +1 for great explanation, that's what I'm looking for